# Facebook shortcut Alt + Del for archiving messages has stopped working

Tags: facebook, keyboard-shortcuts

Some months ago, the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> for archiving messages on Facebook stopped working. From what I can see in this [help file](https://www.facebook.com/help/156151771119453) (the Norwegian version), the shortcut is currently supposed to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>—that does not work either.

Is there a workaround for this? I'm using my Facebook messages actively as an inbox, and this shortcut used to save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

[Techverse](http://www.techverse.net/complete-list-facebook-shortcut-keys/) claimed a complete list (March 5, 2015):

> **Facebook Keyboard Shortcuts**
>
> You can press these buttons on your keyboard to use Facebook faster.
>
> `j`, `k` – Scroll between News Feed stories
>   `p` – Post a new status
>   `l` – Like or unlike the selected story
>   `c` – Comment on the selected story
>   `s` – Share the selected story
>   `o` – Open an attachment from the selected story
>   `enter` - See More of the selected story
>   `/` – Search
>   `q` – Search chat contacts
>   `?` – Show this help dialog
>
> `Ctrl + Alt + 0` - Help
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 1` - Home
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 2` - Timeline
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 3` - Friends
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 4` - Inbox
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 5` - Notifications
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 6` - Settings
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 7` - Activity Log
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 8` - About
>   `Ctrl + Alt + 9` - Terms
>   `Ctrl + Alt + m` - New Message
>
> The Shortcut key combinations for Facebook are different based on
>   which web browser you’re using. However the newsfeed shortcuts are
>   same for all the web browsers. Keyboard combination for different web
>   browsers.
>
> ## Keyboard combination for different web browsers.
>
> Find the right combination of keys for your browser in the list below,
>   and replace # with the access key number listed under Access Keys
>   below.
>
> ```
> Internet Explorer for PC: Alt + #, then Enter
> Firefox for PC: Shift + Alt + #
> Safari for Mac: Ctrl + Opt + #
> Firefox for Mac: Ctrl + Opt + #
> Chrome for Mac: Ctrl + Opt + #
> Chrome for PC: Alt + #
> ```
>
> ## Access Keys
>
> ```
> 0 – Help ( Example: If you are using Chrome for PC, press ALT + 0 to bring up the helpcenter )
> 1 – Home
> 2 – Timeline
> 3 – Friends
> 4 – Inbox
> 5 – Notifications
> 6 – Settings
> 7 – Activity Log
> 8 – About
> 9 – Terms
> ```
>
> ## Keyboard Shortcuts
>
> News Feed
>
> ```
> j and k – Scroll between News Feed stories
> enter/return – See more of the selected story
> p – Post a new status
> l – Like or unlike the selected story
> c – Comment on the selected story
> s – Share the selected story
> o – Open an attachment from the selected story
> / – Search
> q – Search chat contacts
> ? – Open a list of these keyboard shortcuts while in News Feed
> ```
>
> Web Messenger:
>
> ```
> CTRL + g – Search conversations
> CTRL + q – Show/hide keyboard shortcuts
> CTRL + Delete – Archive/unarchive conversation
> CTRL + j – Mark as spam
> CTRL + m – Start a new message
> CTRL + i – Go to Inbox
> CTRL + u – Go to Other
> ```